# pathlib - base filename. Multiple extensions

Tags: python, pathlib

Is there a better way other than resorting to using regular expressions to get the base name of a file?

Taking an example where there are *periods* in filenames too.  `stem` by default just splits on a *period*

```
import Path from pathlib
import re

l = [{'file': '2002/Mr. Deeds (2002)', 'dir': True},
 {'file': '2002/Mr. Deeds (2002)/Mr. Deeds (2002).eng.srt', 'dir': False},
 {'file': '2002/Mr. Deeds (2002)/Mr. Deeds (2002).mp4', 'dir': False},
 {'file': '2016/I.T. (2016).mp4', 'dir': False},
 {'file': '2017/Joshua - Teenager vs. Superpower (2017).mkv', 'dir': False}]

[{"name":Path(d["file"]).name,
  "stem":Path(d["file"]).stem if not d["dir"] else Path(d["file"]).name,
  "base":re.sub(r"([^.,.]*)(\.\w{3,4})*", r"\1", Path(d["file"]).name)
 } 
 for d in l]
```

**output**

```
[{'name': 'Mr. Deeds (2002)',
  'stem': 'Mr. Deeds (2002)',
  'base': 'Mr. Deeds (2002)'},
 {'name': 'Mr. Deeds (2002).eng.srt',
  'stem': 'Mr. Deeds (2002).eng',
  'base': 'Mr. Deeds (2002)'},
 {'name': 'Mr. Deeds (2002).mp4',
  'stem': 'Mr. Deeds (2002)',
  'base': 'Mr. Deeds (2002)'},
 {'name': 'I.T. (2016).mp4', 'stem': 'I.T. (2016)', 'base': 'I.T. (2016)'},
 {'name': 'Joshua - Teenager vs. Superpower (2017).mkv',
  'stem': 'Joshua - Teenager vs. Superpower (2017)',
  'base': 'Joshua - Teenager vs. Superpower (2017)'}]
```

Comment: Basically, no. The reason becomes clear when you consider the implicit assumptions in your regex solution above. There's no specification anywhere dictating that a file extension be 3-4 characters and in many environments and on many OSs it's common to have very long "extensions." If you're in windows you can try to use some registry tricks to pickup recognized extensions, but really it's a losing battle short of maybe an ML solution.

Comment: Do you have to use `pathlib`? What about `os.path.basename` or `os.path.splitext` that works with simple strings.

Comment: @sanitizedUser `os.path.basename` behaves same was as `Path().name` and `os.path.splittext` behaves same way as `Path().stem`. Also I'm trying to move away from effectively legacy use of `os` package

Comment: @kerasbaz good point - interesting if I change to `{2,100}` it sill works and will strip long extensions.  The true issue is *basename* has to contain characters that do not correspond to `\w`